# FileNotFoundException when loading assembly

Tags: vb.net, reflection, load, .net-assembly, filenotfoundexception

I'm getting a FileNotFoundException when i'm trying to access the ExportedTypes of a loaded assembly.

Basically, I have a solution with two projects: Proj1 and Proj2. Proj1 has a reference from Proj2 and i'm trying to load a DLL of Proj1 through their path.
This was the code I tryed:

```
Dim sLoad As System.Reflection.Assembly
Try
   sLoad = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(PathDLL)
   Dim ob = sLoad.ExportedTypes
Catch ex As System.IO.FileNotFoundException
   Dim msh = ex.Message
End Try
```

I already checked AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() and has the assemblie to my Proj2 so I don't understand why it doesn't work.
Already tryed LoadFile too.

This is my error message:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Proj2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

This is my Fusion Log:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Proj2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/jsantos/Source/Workspaces/UP/UP/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\jsantos\Source\Workspaces\UP\UP\bin\Debug\UP.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.
```

Comment: Does Proj2 have any dependencies? You might try loading it in ILSpy if you are unsure.

Comment: No, nothing special. I tried to load Proj2 just to test and I had no problem. I just can't load it from Proj1... and I need to do it through Proj1